# how i can handle webview.canGoBack() on adapter?

Tags: android, webview

I have an Tab activity with cards with url on them as i click on card it will open an webview with given url my problem is that how can i call `webview.canGoBack()` on my adapter.

[image: this is my activity]

after i click on card this window will open help me to handle `canGoback()` on adapter.

[image]

Comment: override onbackpressed in tab activity.

Comment: can you please post your adapter code and how you are showing webview?

Comment: why u guys dicreased my question its not about onbackpressed its about on webview open if i go furtherly on website as i pressed back it come back to main activity

Comment: i've used if (webview.canGoBack() ) {
                       webview.goBack();
                    }

Comment: as on my activities it work fine on them but not on adapter

Comment: in your tab activity's  backpressed method, check which fragment is present and then call if (webview.canGoBack())

Comment: You can make WebView variable static and call it in adaptor, make sure you check if for null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically it should be doable BUT this is **absolutely** not the place for that logic. If you for any reason really need to have WebView in a ListView or RecyclerView, then It'd be cleaner to put it into i.e. Fragment and then let your parent activity notify that fragment on its `onBackPressed()`. But again, to make it all clean, I'd consider using observer pattern i.e. with EventBus where Activity emits and Fragment listens.